# Equations of Motion of a Satellite

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

I'm working on a control problem where I need to know the equations of motion for a satellite orbiting the earth about a central axis. Using Newton's second law, I was able to show that

$\ddot{r}=\dfrac{-Gm_e}{r^2}-r\dot{\theta^2}$,

but I have not been able to get the equations for $\ddot{\theta}$. I know it should be

$\ddot{\theta}=-2\dfrac{\dot{r}\dot{\theta}}{r}$,

but my physics skills are rusty.

An explanation for where this comes from would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: From the formula for the radial acceleration one gets $\;\ddot{r}=\dfrac{-Gm_e}{r^2}+r\dot{\theta^2}$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\ddot{r}=\dfrac{-Gm_e}{r^2}-r\dot{\theta^2}$,

$\ddot{\theta}=-2\dfrac{\dot{r}\dot{\theta}}{r}$,

It is now classical. To derive satellite orbits we use *two* equations of equilibrium in curvilinear coordinates. To get *both* components, twice differentiate the vector $ p=r e^{ i \theta} $ to get the radial and circumferential force components with respect to Sun-Earth line as position vector.

$ \dfrac {\dot{p}} {e^{ i \theta}} = \dot{r}  + i r {\dot{\theta}}  $

$ \dfrac {\ddot{p}} {e^{ i \theta}} =  (\ddot{r} -r\dot{\theta^2}) + i ( r \ddot{\theta} +2 \dot{r} \dot{\theta})  $

*Radial* equilibrium is where Newton famously introduced the inverse law of force as you gave and,

*Circumferential* equilibrium is :

$$ r \ddot{\theta}+ 2 \dot{r}\dot{\theta}= 0$$

as no force acts in this direction. This  on integration gives conserved constant of integration $h$ , the angular momentum

$$ r^2 \dot{\theta} $$

tallying with Kepler's constant swept area rate Law. Introducing $1/r$ as a variable, elliptic orbits with sun focus are obtained.